# How do you open the Javascript console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A moment ago I had minimized VSCode but then accidentally pressed some set of keys. VSCode popped up and displayed a standard Javascript debug console on the right side. While this may very well be an error and VSCode does not intend to expose this console, it's very interesting and I'd love to use it.

Is this an expose feature of VSCode? Is it a legitimate "secret" feature? In either case, how can you access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little console available under the F12 short-cut that has DOM / Styles / Event Listeners and the like.

It is pretty analogous to browser tools.

The main purpose of it is that it exposes the "under the hood" editor - as that is the web page that it is inspecting.

Comment: Yup, I'm sure that's what I ran into. Thanks!